# Having Problem with Response.write(),JavaScript in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have button click event having javascript embedded in response.write something like

``` btn_sub_click(object sender, EventArgs e) { ``Response.Write("<script> alert('alert');window.location='HomePage.aspx'; </script>");``  } ```

Which works fine when I click the button itself.

Now I am using timer to update the page with time and countdown,when the countdown finishes I call the button click event like this:-

`if(Convert.ToInt32(Session["interval"])==0) { btn_sub_Click(btn_sub, null); }`

With this the button click event is called and work is done but the response.write() does not execute until/unless I reload the page or click any other button present on the page?

Am I doing something wrong ?
or Is it totally wrong ?
Either case what should I do ?

Comment: "Am I doing something wrong?"  - yes - **Never** call `Response.Write()` outside of the `Render` function in WebForms, such as in your `btn_sub_click` method.

Comment: **Also, it's 2020 - why are you using WebForms**? It's been deprecated for 12 years now. That's like using Office 97 in 2013.

Comment: @Dai actually never mind I found a way around. Still thank you for your time